# Working of nested class objects?

Tags: c++, oop, object

I am trying to understand the order of exectution of a class which has nested objects of another class inside it. Here's my simple program :

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Alpha
{
    int a;
    public:
    Alpha(int x)
    {
        a=x;
    }
};
class Beta
{   int b;
    public:
    Beta(int y)
    {
        b=y;
    }

};
class Gamma
{
    Alpha A;
    Beta B;
    int c;
    public:
    Gamma(int a,int b, int d): A(a), B(b)
    {
        c=d;
    }
};
void main()
{
    Gamma g(5,6,7);
}
```

As you can see, Gamma has 2 nested objects. Now when the first line of main() is executed, how does the execution start inside the class Gamma? The constructer is called first or the objects/data-members are created first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question of constructor execution order is simple: first, `Gamma` constructor starts, but then it immediately proceeds to initializing `Alpha` and `Beta`, as specified in your initialier list. Once the intializer list is done, the body of `Gamma`'s constructor is executed.

There is an important twist to this: C++ will initialize nested objects in the order in which they are declared in the class, not in the order in which they are listed in the initializer list. In other words, `Alpha` will be initialized ahead of `Beta` even if you reverse `A(a)` and `B(b)`:

```
// The compiler will issue a warning for this
Gamma(int a,int b, int d): B(b), A(a)
{
    c=d;
}
```

Comment: But whenever it encounters Alpha A; shouldnt it go for the default constructer of A? Which really does not exist.. So it should give an error there. Going by this logic: http://ideone.com/Q4QWvC

Comment: @user3693825 This would be true if `Alpha A;` were a declaration of a local or a static variable. However, since it is a member variable of a class, the error is not issued, because your class provides the parameters for calling `Alpha`'s constructor as part of its own constructor. If you remove `A(a)` from the constructor, however, then you would see an error about the default constructor not being there.

Answer (score 1):

> The constructer is called first or the objects/data-members are created first?

From an initializer list the members or base class constructor calls are executed before the constructors body of the containing / inherited class.

You can easily check what's going on placing some output statements in the constructors

```
Alpha(int x) {
    cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
    a=x;
    cout << "Alpha(" << a << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

---

```
Beta(int y) {
    cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;
    b=y;
    cout << "Beta(" << b << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

---

```
Gamma(int a,int b, int d): A(a), B(b) {
    cout << "c = " << c << std::endl;
    c=d;
    cout << "Gamma(" << c << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

Output is

```
a = 0
Alpha(5)
b = 134514731
Beta(6)
c = -1218371596
Gamma(7)
```

See here for a [**fully working sample**](http://ideone.com/H3XiQM).

Answer (score 0):

Objects in the initialization list are initialized first. Then, the body of the constructor inside `{}` is executed.